# Django how to sum the scores of single user for different activities and display in front end only total score

Tags: python, html, css, django

i am posting my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Activity(models.Model):
     activity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
     score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.activity

class Name(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  designation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Name
#from .models import Score
from .models import Activity
from django.db.models import Sum

#from .models import Justification

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    boards = Name.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'boards': boards})


def Score(request):
    boards = Score.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'boards': boards})


def Activity(request):
    boards = Activity.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'boards': boards})
```

html template

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Score Board</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
         <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Score Board</li>
      </ol>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th class="th-sm">Name
          <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Score
          <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Activity
          <i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for board in boards %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                {{ board.name }}
                <small class="text-muted d-block">{{ board.designation }}</small>  </td>
              <td>
                {{ board.score}}
                <class="align-middle">{{ activity }} </td>
                <td>
                {{ board.activity}}
                <class="align-middle">{{ score }} </td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to develop a web portal where for different activities user will be given scores, i am able to add scores to the user but the scores are displayed separtely for the same user, instead i want them to be displayed as total score once in front end.

now the web portal structure is like this

```
user1     10   document
user1     10   installation
```

i want it to display as

```
user1    20
```

and activity column will be hidden in front end

activity column will be seen only by admin in admin page django.

Kindly help me out, i am struck at this point from a month!!!
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a `Score` table in models yet you use it in your Score view function?

Comment: why do you have two 'scores' field. one in `Name` and one in `Activity` ?
add your `Score` model code too